# jQuery: addClass in IF statement not toggling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When a user selects the radio button "Remove" I would like to add the class "disable" to the "a" tag with the heading, at the moment in the fiddle below it adds disable to the "a" tag as soon as it loads.

I added the code to the script which hides the div when remove is selected however it's just an "if" statement and I don't understand how it toggles the show/hide without using "else".

Any help would be appreciated.

```
$('.newsBtns input[type="radio"]').click(function(e) {
  var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
  $('ul.tabsCon08 li').removeClass('current');
  $('.eaCon08').removeClass('current');
  $(this).addClass('current');
  $("#" + tab_id).addClass('current');
});
if ($("input[name=news]:checked").val("close")) {
  $("#newsMainCont").hide();
  $("#newsMainCont").show();
  $(".mainCon").find(".news-link").addClass('disable');
}


$('.eventBtns input[type="radio"]').click(function(e) {
  var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
  $('ul.tabsCon09 li').removeClass('current');
  $('.eaCon09').removeClass('current');
  $(this).addClass('current');
  $("#" + tab_id).addClass('current');
});
if ($("input[name=event]:checked").val("close")) {
  $("#eventMainCont").hide();
  $("#eventMainCont").show();
  $(".mainCon").find('.event-link').addClass('disable');
}
```

[FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/kellyhawker/q0ztuh7v/36/)

Comment: Your `if` statements just run once, when the "click" event handlers  are first established. They're *outside* the event handling functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First - as Pointy said - your if statements is outside click and runs only once. Second your statement

```
if ($("input[name=event]:checked").val("close"))
```

is better to be

```
if ($("input[name=event]:checked").val() === "close")
```

so you can make else statement

https://jsfiddle.net/a5yev9r1/9/

if you write statement like

```
if ($("input[name=event]:checked").val("close"))
```

it will always be true because by writing

```
$("input[name=event]:checked").val("close")
```

you are assigning value "close" to every checked radio button